# Merging cells in Google Documents

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Is it really not possible to merge cells with Google Docs Document?

I have a table like this:

```
-------------
| A | B | C |
-------------
| D |   E   |
-------------
```

Is this possible with Google Docs Document?

I also tried to do table nesting, but then I'm unable to remove padding so it looks terrible.

Comment: Are you talking about Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: No, "Google Docs *Documents*" and not Google Docs Spreadsheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is now possible to merge cells in Google Documents, just like how you would do it in Microsoft Word.

From the [support page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141104?hl=en):

> You can combine or split the cells of a table in a document or a presentation.
>
> ### Merge cells
>
> 1. Open a document or presentation.
> 2. Highlight the cells of a table that you want to combine.
> 3. Open the Table menu.
> 4. Select Merge cells.
>
> ### Unmerge cells
>
> 1. Open a document or presentation.
> 2. Highlight the cells of a table that you want to unmerge.
> 3. Open the Table menu.
> 4. Select Unmerge cells.

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is no.
Here is a group post discussing it:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Docs/thread?tid=7a3c0586722d7c40&hl=en

You could edit the HTML directly but I believe this is only available in the "older" version of the Google Docs editor.

Comment: I tried a hack, to create a table with merged cells in Excel and copy the table to Google Docs. The merge cells were then unmerged.

Comment: Nearly 4 years later, this answer still holds. FWIW, there's a suggestion that Google hasn't implemented this feature due to [a patent claim by Microsoft](http://www.google.com/patents/US6442575).

Comment: At this time Google Documents doesn't allow HTML, by the other hand now allow cell merging (see http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.com/2014/12/table-cell-merging-in-google-docs.html)